# Secure RSS Feeds

Tags: rss, 2007, https

I'm looking for a solution that enables Secure RSS Feeds (https/ssl) for a SharePoint 2007 environment. Any ideas or suggestions?
Third-Party-Tools are welcome :-)
Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for your answers...seems as we have to define our needs first ;-)

Answer (score 2):

We've used NewsGator in the past as an RSS aggregator (which supports https feeds) and it works quite nicely.  Basically they have their NGES Server that aggregates all of the RSS feeds that you'd like, and then they have web parts that you can use in SharePoint to display those feeds inside of SharePoint.

Comment: Will have a look...looks good :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the Dataview webpart and pass explicit authentication details through. It's been years since I tried that though.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to pass RSS data from one site to another?  If so, you'll need to make sure Kerberos authentication is set up in your farm.